# Changing user password through GUI app

Tags: linux, gui, passwd

I was making a GUI application to manage users and groups in Linux!

I'm done with the part where it creates a new user, but stuck with the part where it gives the newly created user a new password.
What my app simply does is to take the required input (username, list of groups, and password) through a GUI and runs a script passing this info as argument.
Let's say we have a user account, xyz.
If I want to change the password for this account, then all I need to do is simply run the command:

```
passwd xyz
```

This will ask for new password. Now I can create a new account using scripts because all the required info is passed in the command line.

```
useradd -m -G users -g "groups" -s /bin/bash "UserName"
```

I can run a script through Qt app and create the user, but
in `passwd cmd`, the input is asked in the other line. How does one deal with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the right answer here is: **don't shell to a command-line tool — use a library call**. This will let you handle errors better, and avoids risk-prone passing of the password on a command line.

One library you can use is [libuser](https://fedorahosted.org/libuser/), which is relatively simple and has C and Python bindings.

Comment: @mattdm-Can you suggest some tutorials i mean some reference usage help! :)

Answer (score 5):

As root you can systematically set a user's password via a script using this method:

```
$ echo -n "$passwd" | passwd "$uname" --stdin
```

#### Generating passwords

I like using the command line tool [`pwgen`](http://pwgen-win.sourceforge.net/) to generate passwords.

```
$ passwd="`pwgen -1cny | sed 's/[\$\!]/%/g'`"

$ pwgen --help
Usage: pwgen [ OPTIONS ] [ pw_length ] [ num_pw ]

Options supported by pwgen:
  -c or --capitalize
    Include at least one capital letter in the password
  -A or --no-capitalize
    Don't include capital letters in the password
  -n or --numerals
    Include at least one number in the password
  -0 or --no-numerals
    Don't include numbers in the password
  -y or --symbols
    Include at least one special symbol in the password
  -s or --secure
    Generate completely random passwords
  -B or --ambiguous
    Don't include ambiguous characters in the password
  -h or --help
    Print a help message
  -H or --sha1=path/to/file[#seed]
    Use sha1 hash of given file as a (not so) random generator
  -C
    Print the generated passwords in columns
  -1
    Don't print the generated passwords in columns
  -v or --no-vowels
    Do not use any vowels so as to avoid accidental nasty words
```

#### But isn't this insecure?

No. The password is being passed via STDIN to `passwd` so though it might be possible for someone to snoop on the processes via `ps`, even that shouldn't allow a user to see root's processes, the handing of the password to `passwd` is walled off.

#### Example

Say I run this command in one terminal as root:

```
$ ( sleep 10; echo "supersecret" | passwd "samtest" --stdin ) &
[1] 13989
```

I then run `ps` in another terminal:

```
$ ps -AOcmd | grep pass
14046 passwd samtest --stdin      R pts/11   00:00:00 passwd samtest --stdin
```

After the password is changed in the 1st terminal:

```
[root@greeneggs ~]# Changing password for user samtest.
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

#### What about the echo to passwd?

Even this does not leak the password. Here's another test demonstrating this. First we start this command in a secondary terminal. This will collect output from `ps`.

```
$ while [ 1 ]; do ps -eaf2>&1 | grep -E "echo|pass";done | tee ps.txt
```

We then run our password setting command:

```
$ echo "supersecret" | passwd "samtest" --stdin &
[1] 20055
$ Changing password for user samtest.
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.

[1]+  Done                    echo "supersecret" | passwd "samtest" --stdin
```

Checking the contents of `ps.txt` shows that the password is not leaked:

```
$ grep supersecret ps.txt
$
```

Changing the `ps` command we use to `ps -eaf` also doesn't leak it.

Comment: so its gonna put "$passwd" as password for user "$uname" ?

Comment: @Chronix01 - those are variables, but yes the password for `$uname` would be `$passwd`.

Comment: wow if that works trust me buddy u saved the day! :D

Comment: @Chronix01 - it should work fine, I use a method similar for building accounts automatically.

Comment: also how do i check for the current password? will i have to decode gshadow?

Comment: @Chronix01 - `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: Wouldn't this show the user's password in `ps`, even if only for a second?  Seems like a security issue; if someone was aware you did this, they could monitor password changes through your GUI.

Comment: @sapi - no, only root could see this process or someone that had `sudo` rights. Even then this command runs so quickly I'd doubt you could catch it. `ps` does not allow uses to see all the processes, only their own.

Comment: @sim that's wrong. Issuing `ps -AOcmd` gives me the list of all the processes and their command lines — without requiring me to be root. This will of course list `echo` with password as its argument. Still, you could just pipe the password from `pwgen` to `passwd` directly, then no one could read it except owner equipped with debugger.

Comment: @Ruslan - no, the contents via a pipe are not shown on the command line. Hence the use of the --stdin switch. So someone would see the passwd command being run but nothing more in that scenario. See my updates.

Comment: @slm no, I'm talking not about pipe. I mean the `echo` command. Clearly it has `echo -n ThePassword123` command line, which will be visible via `ps` if you are lucky enough to catch it running. And on my system `which echo` tells `/bin/echo`, so it clearly may be not a builtin, for which the `ps` would be unable to see the command line.

Comment: @Ruslan - see updates.

Comment: @Ruslan - the use of a variable to store the password is likely the weak link, so your comment about piping the output of `pwgen directly into `passwd` would fix that. But in this scenario I opted for readability since other less novice scripter would be supporting this script, and the number of accounts created in my usecase was < 5-10 per year.

Comment: @sim well got and issue i tried your command but it doesn't seem to work.
I get an error

`passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin'`

Comment: @Chronix01 - what distro are you using?  What's the version of `passwd`?

Comment: @slm - im using Arch linux, though i solved the issue by `chpasswd`

Comment: @Chronix01 - cool, so your issues are all resolved then?

Comment: As i continue with the application i get new issues i solve them move on to the next part! :D

Comment: The reason why echo is not appearing in `ps` is because it's a usually shell builtin. (Another reason could conceivably be a race condition, but that sounds unlikely.)  I would not recommend using echo unless you know for sure it will be a shell builtin.

Answer (score 1):

`passwd --help` on my box indicates that `root` can run it with `--stdin` to feed it the new password on stdin.

Answer (score 0):

The chpasswd command reads a list of user name/password pairs from the command line to update a group of existing users. Each line is in the format

```
user_name:password
```

This command is intended to be used in large system environments where many accounts are created at a single time. To read about more options of this command, type

```
man chpasswd
```